# Dynamically resize luxor(XUL) button in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, xul

I have a button defined in my .xul file like this:

```
<button icon="PASTE" id="crew" label="Add crew" command="add_crew"/>
```

which is one of multiple buttons in my vbox, but the only one with text that should be dynamicaly changed on runtime.

```
<vbox>
    <button icon="NEW" id="new" label="New" command="new"/>
    <spacer style="height:5px"/>
    <button icon="PASTE" id="crew" label="Add crew" command="add_crew"/>
    <spacer style="height:5px"/>
    <button icon="DELETE" id="remove" label="Remove" command="delete"/>
</vbox>
```

In my .java file I get this button via

```
this.CREW = (JButton)this.form.getElementById("crew").getJComponent();
```

Later in my .java file (in refresh method), I want to accomplish that text inside my this.CREW button is changed based on if statement.

```
    String html;
    if (this.DJ == true){
        html = "<html>" + this.getLang("add_dj").replaceAll("\n", "<br/>") + "</html>";
    }else{
       html = "<html>" + this.getLang("add_crew").replaceAll("\n", "<br/>") + "</html>"; 
    }

    this.CREW.setText(html);
```

where getLang("add_dj") returns "Add DJ" and getLang("add_crew") "Add Crew Member". Of course, I want this text to be in multiple rows and I would love my button to resize based on text it contains.